# Two different array in JavaScript and combine Single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two different array parent and child relational array and combine single array.

this is parent array:-
`const cat = ['a','b','c'];`

this is Child array:-
`const sub =[{name:'cloth',cat:['a','b']},{name:'feshion',cat:['b','a']}]`

the output Combine Two array and make single array, I am using map and filter method, It doesn't work
the output should be like this
`const parent =[{name:'a',sub:['cloth','feshion']},{name:'b',sub:['cloth','feshion']},{name:'c',sub:[]}]`

Please help me, and Please give me any Idea

Comment: So loop over the parent with map and combine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const result = cat.map(name => ({name, sub: sub.filter(s => s.cat.includes(name)).map(s => s.name)}));
```

produces:

```
[
   { "name": "a", "sub": ["cloth", "feshion"] },
   { "name": "b", "sub": ["cloth", "feshion"] },
   { "name": "c", "sub": [] }
]
```

Here's an expanded version of that line, easier to follow:

```
const result = cat.map(catName => {
   const subs = sub
      .filter(s => s.cat.includes(catName))
      .map(s => s.name);

   return {name: catName, sub: subs};
});
```

Run the code:

```js
const cat = ['a','b','c'];
const sub =[{name:'cloth',cat:['a','b']},{name:'feshion',cat:['b','a']}];
const result = cat.map(name => ({name, sub: sub.filter(s => s.cat.includes(name)).map(s => s.name)}));
console.log(result);
```